# Sending an email from PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

**Foreword, I am not sure whether stackoverflow is the appropriate site but neither Server Fault nor Web Applications appeared to be appropriate either. If you feel another site is better, please feel free to move.**

I am trying to get an email sent from PHP and struggle with the *sendmail* configuration. Sending it via PHP does not really result in any output (`mail()` after all only returns a boolean) and trying to send it from the command line results in a "connection refused" error, which I presume comes from the fact that I stopped the sendmail service. As I dont need to receive any mails though, I do not need the service.

So how does one need to configure sendmail to work without its background service and simply send the data/email it receives via the command line?

*Alternatively, if someone knew a lightweight alternative to sendmail (not necessarily postfix :) ) which only takes email from the command line and nothing else, I'd be grateful of course as well.*

Comment: usually there's very little needing configuration with sendmail. the out-of-box settings in most distributions that ship with sendmail will work as is... but no, you can't really have sendmail without a sendmail daemon. sendmail the daemon checks for both outgoing and incoming mail.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc, but this is exactly what I want to avoid. I dont care about incoming email and only want to send. Is there any argument/setting which could achieve this? Or would you know any alternative MTA which does not require this load of services and configuration? :)

Comment: You NEED to start the sendmail service. I've had this issue before.

Comment: @ramonovski This is exactly what I want to avoid. As I said I do not receive any emails, so I wouldnt want yet an additional service. I basically just want to send from a PHP script.

Comment: you can tell sendmail to bind only to the localhost/127.0.0.1 address, so anyone external trying to connect to send stuff to you would only get a connection refused.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. Would you know any **lightweight** alternative not requiring a background service?

Answer (score 3):

Options:

1. [Configure Sendmail as outbound-only.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-sendmail-as-outbound-submission-mta/)
2. [PHPmailer.](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

And you can't stop the Sendmail service and still expect to have Sendmail do anything for you. That's just... ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I have only read the first few lines but it might be promising. PHPMailer is unfortunately not an option as it is third-party code which relies on `mail()`.

Comment: What is ridiculous about it? I dont need a service doing anything in the background. I need something which acts upon being called and this does not require a service.

Comment: @user2425954 doing nothing in the background except for, you know, *sending mail*. As a very broad overview Sendmail boils down to a submission agent that puts mail into the queue, and a delivery agent that takes messages out of the queue and delivers them. The submission agent runs on-demand and is why `mail()` is returning `true` because it's put the messages into the queue, the problem you're having is that the other half of the equation is turned off. I don't have enough space in the comments to describe how necessary it is to run in the background, but *it is*.

Comment: This might be a sendmail architecture related issue, but for sending an email you dont need a background service (letting the queuing part aside, which would be a conscious decision then). Sendmail could simply take this in consideration and use a direct approach without service.

Comment: @user2425954 the list of things that Sendmail *could* or *should* do could choke a herd of wide-necked animals, and since Sendmail is the de facto standard MTA of MTAs [of which most follow Sendmail's lead] you'll be better off adjusting to how it works rather than debating why it does what.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to send directly via another SMTP server using Pear's mail package.

More info here: http://tltech.com/info/php-mail-via-smtp/